# firebase: "Could not parse auth token."

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello i am using firebase with php and using this [library](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php#supported-commands).

I am getting this error."Could not parse auth token."

My auth token is correct because i have used same token with node.js also.

my code looks like this

```
       require "vendor/autoload.php";
       const DEFAULT_URL = 'https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com';
       const DEFAULT_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

       $firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN );  

        $data = [
        "Website_Name"=> $Website_Name,
        "Username" =>  $Username,
       "Password"=> $Password,
       "website_link"=> $website_link,
       "id"=> $id,
       ];



        $path = "per_users";
        $res = $firebase->push('/per_users', $data);
        // per_users is the name of the table
        var_dump($res);
```

can you please tell me what exactly i am doing wrong.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using somethink like this and it works for me. without any library. simple.

```
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR_FIREBASE_API_KEY' ); //<--- here comes your api key from firebase
$registrationIds = array( "devices firebasetoken here." ); //<--- here comes device token (firebase generated token.)
// prep the bundle
$msg = array(
    'body'  => "message text",
    'title'     => "message title",
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
        'notification'      => $msg
    );

$headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
 $result = curl_exec($ch );
 curl_close( $ch );
 echo $result;
```

Comment: can you guide me little bit.. how i should use this in my code??  because its looks totally different like curl and all the the stuff

Comment: I have changed code and added where and what you shall change. it is very simple code.

Comment: This code i'm using for myself and it is working perfect. (i chenged it now) :)

Comment: that doesn't work man ... i am getting error "[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}""

Comment: This Solution works for me. I think your problem is now in your device coding

Comment: Can you post your device code? Paste it on patebin then send link

Answer (score 14):

I found the following solution worked, if anyone would still want to use topic starter's [library](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php#supported-commands):

1. Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and select your project.
2. Go to Project Settings (press the gear icon beside Overview in the upper left)
3. Go to the Service Accounts tab
4. Select Database Secrets, show and copy the database secret key for the library's `const DEFAULT_TOKEN`

[image]

Comment: Database secrets are depreciated do you have a solution for using firebase admin sdk?