# Vue.js+Firebase: 401 error, 'unauthorized'

Tags: firebase, vue.js

When I try to use post method in my Vue project:

```
this.$http.post("https://vuejs-blog-b91df.firebaseio.com/posts.json", this.blog).then(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   this.submitted = true;}
```

the console throws me an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Uncaught (in promise) 
Response
body: {error: "Permission denied"}
bodyText: "{↵  "error" : "Permission denied"↵}↵"
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: false
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
url: "https://project-name.firebaseio.com/posts.json"
data: (...)
__proto__: Object
```

Where and how should I put firebase project apiKey and other authorization data to succeed?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. One simple question: why don’t you use the JavaScript SDK to query the database instead of the REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Authentication with access_token

Based on firbase authentication [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth), I think you must change your request URL to smth like this:

```
const token = 'token'; // get token somewhere
this.$http
  .post(`https://vuejs-blog-b91df.firebaseio.com/posts.json?access_token=${token}`, this.blog)
  .then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
     this.submitted = true;
  });
```

### Authentication with ID token

Or you may use ID token authentication like this:

```
const token = 'token'; // get token somewhere
this.$http
  .post(`https://vuejs-blog-b91df.firebaseio.com/posts.json?auth=${token}`, this.blog)
  .then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
     this.submitted = true;
  });
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) you can find how to get ID token on client

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexander! It worked! The only thing I'd like to add is that standart instruction for generating tokens doesn't work properly, I got 401 errors ('could not parse auth token' or 'Expected an ID token, but was given a custom token'), so that the 'database-secret-related' answer given by raiser00 in this discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550635/firebase-could-not-parse-auth-token) helped me to succeed.